# Compilation Error - The compiler failed with error code -1071316749. in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I changed my Windows to Windows 11 and now when I open my previous projects it gives me this error

error : The compiler failed with error code -1071316749.

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express>C:\Users\Alireza_k22\source\repos\ChoobinSanat\WebApplication1\bin\roslyn\csc.exe /t:library /utf8output /nostdlib+ /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\42dfa001\0014e68e_5587d401\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\4b1bc730\0014e68e_5587d401\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\685fca4c\0014e68e_5587d401\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\2d864d5f\00a532e9_5487d401\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\14ee411e\00eeb1f8_5487d401\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\d3b88b05\005ce124_966acd01\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\80e4482b\00c46690_25aece01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\b7c095c2\00af91ba_2518cf01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\96e22c5e\0014e68e_5587d401\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\1ee0575f\00a26c3d_2027cf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\099ae19b\74f4961a_1c16da01\WebApplication1.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\18c98ca0\00cc5842_e2f8d401\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\assembly\dl3\08053e2a\003993af_6d45d401\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" /out:"C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\App_global.asax.t4hfac7s.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /warnaserror- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701  "C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\App_global.asax.t4hfac7s.0.cs" "C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\App_global.asax.t4hfac7s.1.cs"
```

But when I create a new project, it runs perfectly and this really bothers me
I looked on the internet, somewhere it was written to change the compiler in web.config, I did this, but unfortunately my problem was not solved.

```
 <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
  </compilers>
```

Can the problem be from IIS?
What should I do to solve this problem?

Thank you for helping me...

Comment: Open the referenced file "`C:\Users\Alireza_k22\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\897231a3\c08b8969\App_global.asax.t4hfac7s.0.cs`" in VS and look for issues. Ditto for `App_global.asax.t4hfac7s.1.cs`.

Comment: Exit code `-1071316749`  is equivalent to `0xC02500F3` which doesn't seem to be a Win32 error-code, HRESULT, nor a COM error. _curious_

Comment: You have shown us the csc command that is run to compile the code which is next to useless in debugging this. Can you include the details of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this problem by removing the dll containing resolyn
For this, go to manage nuget package and delete the corresponding DLL in the installed section
This method solved my problem. Hope this helps you too